# dxf viewer in React x TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, viewer

I'm leaning react x typescript these days and
I was wondering if I can use "[three-dxf](https://github.com/gdsestimating/three-dxf)" and "[dxf-parser](https://github.com/gdsestimating/dxf-parser/issues)" in my React x TypeScript app to show dxf files.
I’d like to use like these modules but it seems it doesn’t work.

I'd like to know if these modules are available in React x TypeScript or not ..
Or If you know any ideas about importing them to app please let me know ...

in a component, I wrote require code like this ↓

```js
const Viewer = require('three-dxf');
const DxfParser = require('dxf-parser').default;
```

I can't seem to get it to work.

Thank you .

Comment: I also tried making a file for types because they don't have @types.